# Reserve flash memory space in TI cc26xx

Tags: c, linker, contiki, flash-memory

I am currently trying to reserve a sector of the flash memory in the linker file, to save some data to it (using the driverlib API). I first flash the script writing to the specific memory addresses, then I run my application which reads the saved data.

Unfortunately whenever I flash, the data is lost. Therefore I am trying to change the linker file and reserve some space but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I will appreciate any help or hints.

```
MEMORY
{
    /* Flash Size 128 KB minus the CCA area below (88 bytes) */
    /* OLD: FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x0001FFA8 */
    FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x0001FF88

    /*
     * Custom reserved memory space with size of 32 bytes
     */
    CNVM (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x0001FF88, LENGTH = 32

    /*
     * Customer Configuration Area and Bootloader Backdoor configuration
     * in flash, up to 88 bytes
     */
    FLASH_CCFG (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0001FFA8, LENGTH = 88

    /* RAM Size 20KB */
    SRAM (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00005000

    /* Application can use GPRAM region as RAM if cache is disabled in CCFG */
    GPRAM (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x11000000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
}

/*. Highest address of the stack. Used in startup file .*/
_estack = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM); /* End of SRAM */

/*. Generate a link error if heap and stack don’t fit into RAM .*/
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x100;

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH = 0

    .text:
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    } > CNVM

    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH

    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx*)
    } > FLASH

    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM

    .ccfg :
    {
        KEEP(*(.ccfg))
    } > FLASH_CCFG

    /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
    ._user_heap_stack :
    {
      . = ALIGN(4);
      . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
      . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
      . = ALIGN(4);
    } > SRAM

    .gpram :
    { 
    } > GPRAM

}
```

Comment: How do you flash the board?

Comment: I guess you are trying to reserve space in between the application of space on the flash, `CNVM (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x0001FF88, LENGTH = 32`. I would suggest to move the custom reserved space to the end of the Flash and when you erase and flash the firmware just erase only the size of your application and then flash the application.

Comment: @GauravPathak he's already using a region as close to the "end of the flash" as sensible.

Comment: @kfx I see! `FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x0001FF88`. Thanks!

Comment: @kfx I am using the TI UniFlash tool.

Comment: You need to fins a way how to tell Uniflash to avoid erasing / overwriting the memory region of interest then. The loader script looks fine to me, but is just the first of the two  steps you need to do

Comment: I suspected that too so I am already looking into it, but the linker script is already not compiling and returning an error at the ``.text: { *(.rodata*) } > CNVM``

Comment: So now it compiles, . There was a missing space after ``.text :``

Comment: This linker command file section: `.text:
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    } > CNVM` is wrong. For three reasons.  1) the `.rodata` is already in the first .text section.  and 2)  `CNVM` is not defined as a MEMORY segment and 3) there is already defined a `.text` section

Comment: @user3629249 well any idea what to put instead of ``.rodata`` and ``.text`` to make it correct? CNVM is already defined in the MEMORY segment, just check the linker script above.

Comment: Your right, I was wrong about the definition of the CNVM memory segment..  What section have you defined (in the source code) for the contents of the CNVM?  That is the segment name to use rather than `.text` and use that segment name, not `.rodata` for the input to that segment.

Comment: @user3629249 That makes sense. So I tried the following``.cnvm : { KEEP(*(.cnvm)) } > CNVM`` under ``SECTIONS`` but the data still gets deleted after re-flashing. Btw I am not calling any section in my source code, I am just writing to a particular address (contained in CNVM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the linker approach didn't provide the desired result in my case. What I ended up doing instead is editing the generated binary file from my code before flashing the sensortag.

Using the hexdump command on linux as follows `hexdump generated_binary_file.bin` one can notice that each line includes the start memory address (for a certain range of addresses) followed by the data written to this range.

And so using a small python script one can change the values in a certain line and generate its own modified binary file that will be later flashed to the sensortag. The memory address content can be read with a certain function that you include in your initial code (before bin generation & editing) such `memcpy()` for example.